# Skipping search results page based on autocomplete filtering

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete, filtering

I have autocomplete filtering search set up and need to modify the script below. What I need is when the user is typing the query the autocomplete search filtering shows relevant results and when clicked on any of them the user is taken directly to that particular page. Currently the user is always taken to search results. Basically, just want to skip search results step.

```
        function fwp_redirect() {
            if ('get' == FWP.permalink_type) {
                var query_string = FWP.build_query_string();
                if ('' != query_string) {
                    query_string = '?' + query_string;
                }
                var url = query_string;
            }
            else {
                var url = window.location.hash;
            }
            window.location.href = '<?php echo get_post_type_archive_link( 'job_listing' ); ?>' + url;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the result page, if it returns **only one result** - then it can automatically redirect to the listing page instead of rendering the page. All of this will happen in server side. The user will be redirected to the listing page straight without showing the search result page.

Comment: Thanks for getting back, but how can I achieve that? That's the main issue here, don't know what steps to take to do exactly what you said.

Comment: Well, I think you misunderstood me. There is only one result, because when they start typing in the query, autocomplete should display the full listing title page and every listing has its own name. How can I modify the link so it will take them to the listing page they typed in?